# A command to switch airplane mode in gnome?

Tags: wifi, gnome, nmcli

I am looking for a single command that switches airplane mode on/off. Actually I want to manipulate my fn+f10 key to switch airplane mode. I tried to add custom shortcut from gnome settings but it only allows one command. I know that `nmcli radio wifi off` works fine but I need to enter two commands to turn it on/off. Is there a way to do it with one command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rfkill`:

```
alias airplane-toggle="rfkill list | grep -q '\byes\b' && rfkill unblock all || rfkill block all"
```